# how to change this query in Hibernate? comma separated list in one column

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

[Previous output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTGvv.png)

SQL query -

```
select 
     employeeid,FamilyPay,IsActive,
    stuff((
        select  ',' + u.IndividualPay
        from yourtable u
        where u.IndividualPay = IndividualPay
        order by u.IndividualPay
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as IndividualPay
from yourtable
group by EmployeeID,FamilyPay,IsActive
```

output :-
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsXEv.png)

Can someone help me changing this in Hibernate query ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a misuse of HQL to replicate that SQL query. HQL is a query language for Hibernate entities, not a replacement for SQL, thus you need to work at the level of Hibernate entities.

You can use `@Formula` to directly bind the subquery result to a entity field:

```
@Formula("stuff(( select ',' + u.IndividualPay from yourtable u where u.IndividualPay = IndividualPay order by u.IndividualPay for xml path('') ),1,1,'')")
private String individualPay;
```

When Hibernate generates the query, it will insert this SQL fragment into the generated SQL.

It is more important to define your entity correctly. The HQL should be simple.

Comment: Thanks sh0rug0ru. i am not familiar with HQL much. how can i write this in HQL way.
there are three tables. 
1. Employee - employeeid, Familypay
2.Employee-individual pay mapping - employeeid,individual pay
3. Active - employeeid,isactive

Comment: Read up on the Hibernate Query language. There are plenty of examples of grouping [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping).